# Regex to validate a string

Tags: regex, xsd

I'm trying to validate a string in an xsd that requires the use of a regex.  The string will take the form of the following...

JOE~PETE~SAM~BOB

and the following are considered valid...

```
JOE
~PETE
JOE~SAM~
~~~BOB
JOE~PETE~~
```

also, each of the names between the ~ can only be a maximum of 6 characters (or digits) and there can only be a maximum of 4 names.

The regex I'm trying right now is...

[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,6}[~]{0,1}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,6}[~]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,4}[~]{0,1}

but am wondering if their is a better solution.

NOTE:  I should clarify a bit further... if there are only 4 names allowed, that means there would only be 3 ~'s at the most allowed.  The tildes denote position, so if ~~~BOB occurred, that would mean the position 1,2, and 3 were empty, and the 4th was occupied by BOB.  Also, if the you had JOE~~~, JOE is in the first position, and the rest are empty.  Zero or more names could be in any of the 4 positions.  Also, symbols like .,*, space, and others are allowed.

Comment: Are `~~~`, `A~~~B`, or empty strings valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you're getting at

```
^[^~]{0,6}(~[^~]{0,6}){0,3}$
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved it.  A colleague of mine who fancies himself a regex expert was actually stumped on this one for hours, so I really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
^(~*\b[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}\b~*){0,4}$
```

Assuming there is no limit to the number of `~`s between, before, and after the names.

The `\b` escape sequence matches "borders" between words - that is, the space between any alphanumeric and any non-alphanumeric character.

Also, Pro Tip: the `\w` escape sequence matches the same thing as `[0-9a-zA-Z]`. The above regex could be shortened to:

```
^(~*\b\w{1,6}\b~*){0,4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Are empty strings valid? What about strings consisting solely of tildes? If so, the following will work:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]{0,6}~?){0,4}$
```

Comment: That would match names longer than 6 chars tho.

Comment: Also fails for ~JOE~PETE~SAM~BOB

Comment: Ah, good calls. My bad. I'll leave this alone, since my fix would basically be what Chris has already posted.